# Rails 4 - how to make a link to a PDF file (name.PDF)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wicked-pdf

I am generating PDF files and my link look like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Invoice', display_invoice_path(invoice.id), :format => :pdf %>
```

When I click on this, it takes me to **/display_invoice/123456789** (it's an HTML version).

In the controller action is following:

```
def display_invoice
    if params[:invoice_number]
      @invoice = ...

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.pdf do
          #render pdf: '123',                  # file name
          render pdf: params[:invoice_number],
                 layout: 'layouts/application.pdf.erb'#,  # layout used
                 #show_as_html: params[:debug].present?    # allow debuging
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

and in the routes:

```
  get '/display_invoice/:invoice_number', to: 'invoices#display_invoice', :as => 'display_invoice'
```

After clicking the link, I'd like to have in the URL **/display_invoice/INVOICE_NUMBER.pdf** - currently, there's just **/display_invoice/INVOICE_NUMBER**.

How to open it with the ".pdf" suffix?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to add `:format => :pdf` into the `display_invoice_path` helper like `display_invoice_path(invoice, :format => :pdf)`

Answer (score 11):

You need to add the pdf mime type.

Add the following line to the file *config/initializers/mime_types.rb*:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#restful-downloads for details.

**EDIT:**

The format needs to be part of the path helper:

```
display_invoice_path(invoice.id, :format => :pdf)
```

Comment: I've added this to the mentioned file. Btw, when I manually put to the URL the PDF suffix, like **/display_invoice/INVOICE_NUMBER.pdf**, then the PDF file is properly generated, but the problem is that I don't know how to set up the **link_to** for displaying the PDF file.

Comment: I updated my answer, you need to include the format in the path helper.

Comment: why I'm getting a  warning: already initialized constant Mime::PDF
 and warning: previous definition of PDF was here. Is it already loaded in Rails 4 > ?

Comment: @aldrien.h what happens if you omit the mime type registration? If it still works you can assume that it's already loaded somewhere else. This can be either rails itself, or a gem, or somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 3):

use this code instead of your code

```
<%= link_to 'Invoice', display_invoice_path(invoice.id, :format => :pdf) %>
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem.

Comment: Difference is GET and POST

Answer (score 0):

There is a new syntax without using Hash Rocket

```
<%= link_to "Invoice", display_invoice_path(invoide, format: :pdf), target: "_blank" %>
```

If you want to have URL in anchor tag then use `.._url` instead of `.._path`

```
<%= link_to "Invoice", display_invoice_url(invoide, format: :pdf), target: "_blank" %>
```