# Linking to pdf in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I have a rails app where I am providing summary information re: various legal opinions.  The information about each opinion is called from MySQL.  In addition to the information from the database, I would also like to provide a link to a PDF of that particular opinion.  Currently the pdfs are all stored in a folder labeled `"op_pdf"` with in the `"assets folder."`  Each pdf is named using the `opinion.id` for that opinion (opinion with id = 1 is 1.pdf, 2 is 2.pdf, etc).

I've researched this extensively but keep finding conflicting information.

1. The code I am currently using (that does not work) is:

   ```
   '<%= link_to @opinion.name, asset_path "op_pdf/@opinion.id", :format => :pdf)  %>'
   ```
2. In `initializers/myme_types.rb` I have:

   ```
   Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
   ```

The 3rd step is my issue.  I have to do something in the controller and/or routes.  I am working from this - [Rails 4 - how to make a link to a PDF file (name.PDF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502322/rails-4-how-to-make-a-link-to-a-pdf-file-name-pdf)

but it seems to be overkill for what I need.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: post your controller code for this action.  Normally you'll use the "send_file" method in it.

Comment: i haven't attempted it - i will look into send_file

Comment: Ok I'll give you a quick summary of how I do it for reference.  Bear in mind this only works if you're not generating pdf's from scratch but only serving pdf's already made.

Comment: thats all I am after - no need to generate pdfs.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey basically you'll want to use the "paperclip gem" for adding these pdfs.  Follow the gem docs and it will handle the routing for you.  Once you've added the gem and set it up, following the docs youll want to add the paperclip columns to your table.  Then youll add the "has_attachments" method from the docs to your model file.  Then any pdfs you add, the routing and all will be taken care of.  Then link_to an action (we'll call it download) and that should call the send_file method like:  
send_file(@pdf.pdf.path, disposition: "attachment")    #If you get stuck I'll post a full answer

Comment: What is the specific error you are receiving? when you say it does not work what is happening?